# Airport express and Airport utility

Tags: network, airport

I moved and had to change my network.

After juggling for reconfiguring my airport express station, I found out it was impossible to connect to them, even after a factory reset : they just would NOT appear in the Airport Utility 6.2 program that is meant to manage those things.

However, I could see all of them appear in the [bonjour browser](http://www.tildesoft.com/), so there is no network issues.

Faced with that issue, I saw some other people could not either use their Airport Express anymore. I am now using the old utility as they [are](http://coreyjmahler.com/2013/03/08/airport-utility-5-6-on-os-x-v10-8-mountain-lion/), which necessitates a hack, but works perfectly.

However, I still don't understand if there are anything we are doing wrong.

That seems wrong that Apple gave no way to use its product.
Has anyone be able to manage its airport express with standard Apple program ? 
I dont understand the rationale of what happens and must be missing some information..

Comment: Are you trying to connect using the previous Airport Utility settings (Location)?

Comment: No, that is why I need to reset and access the express. but the only way I found is this hack of using a modified old version of airport utility.

Comment: Try using new location in Airport utility and reconnecting. Did you try using the cable ?

Answer (score 2):

Download the Lion version 5.6 of [Airport Utility](https://support.apple.com/kb/DL1482) , which actually works with setting up / reconfiguring an Airport Express.

Both versions (ML comes with 6.x) can be used on Mountain Lion. Keep both around, for now.

Though once setup, my AE responds well to AU 6.x.

I don't know why .. but then, ours is *not* to reason why, is it.

Comment: He is already using the 5.6 as hack fix.

Comment: I'm saying it's not a hack fix in Mountain Lion but a perfectly well-working utility, thanks.